# gcc/clang vs. MSVC: Does a static_assert in a function have to be evaluated if the return type is bad?

Tags: c++11, gcc, visual-c++, clang, language-lawyer

In this very reduced example, is the compiler required to evaluate the `static_assert`?

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
auto foo(T t) -> void
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<T, int>::value, "T has to be int");
}

auto test(int) -> void
{}

int main()
{
    test(foo("7"));
}
```

- gcc and clang agree on evaluating the `static_assert`.
- MSVC 2015 on the other hand ignores the `static_assert`.

What does the standard require?

### Background:

I am providing a combination of a template-argument-dependent return-type and `static_assert` to indicate correct or incorrect template arguments in a function. This way, you can use the return-type for compile-time evaluation, or you can just run into the `static_assert`.

However, if I cannot be sure that my `static_assert` is actually evaluated, I need to rethink a few things...

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/) (this fails with a different error, mainly conversion from `void` to `int` in the function `test`. [Same thing with gcc](https://ideone.com/cfnkpa). My MSCV 2015 doesn't ignore `static_assert`

Comment: You're saying that your MSVC 2015 shows the text "T has to be int"?

Comment: Yes, the code doesn't compile because of "T has to be int"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for an implementation to be compliant, it must meet the following requirement:

> If a program contains a violation of any diagnosable rule or an
>   occurrence of a construct described in this Standard as
>   “conditionally-supported” when the implementation does not support
>   that construct, a conforming implementation shall issue at least one
>   diagnostic message.

It doesn't say "at least one diagnostic message for each error", but "at least one diagnostic message" period.

Comment: Do you have a link to your source?

Comment: Ah, found it, [intro.compliance] in the standard. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing a compiler must do is provide a diagnostic when there's a diagnosable standard violation. I sure hope MSVC does that.

`static_assert` in a program that is ill-formed even without this `static_assert` may or may not trigger, because you cannot even talk about what's `true` and what's `false` and what's a declaration in an ill-formed program.

Another example in the same spirit:

```
void[] foo() {
  static_assert (false, "Oops");
}
```

g++ only complains about an invalid return type, and clang also triggers the static assert.